Fast AI Error With Basic Image Recognition Example
I'm following the fast AI course lesson 1 and I'm trying out the "Is It A Bird" example. Everything works fine with a notebook, but I started to refactor the components as a pipeline and one of the pipeline step is to train the model like this:
def train_model_from_data():
    learn = vision_learner(dls, resnet34, metrics=[partial(accuracy, axis=1)])
    learn.fine_tune(6)
    return learn

When I ran the Python file containing that method, I ran into an error as below:
  File "/home/myuser/Projects/Private/ml-projects/nn-playground/src/models/is_it_a_bird/train_model.py", line 74, in download_train_dump_model
    learner = train_model_from_data()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/myuser/Projects/Private/ml-projects/nn-playground/src/models/is_it_a_bird/train_model.py", line 62, in train_model_from_data
    learn.fine_tune(6)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/myuser/Projects/Private/ml-projects/nn-playground/myenv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastcore/basics.py", line 503, in __getattr__
    if attr is not None: return getattr(attr,k)

Any idea what the error could be?
